# Error recording voice at16000 khz 16bit mono little endian wav file in android device

Tags: android, record, wav, audio-recording, sample-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to convert or record .wav file in 16khz 16bit mono little-endian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260476/how-to-convert-or-record-wav-file-in-16khz-16bit-mono-little-endian)

I want to implement audio recording from an android device at 16000 khz 16bit mono little endian wav file.

I had implemented the logic in android like this. I'm using one class name as extaudiorecorder.

```
public class ExtAudioRecorder {
    private final static int[] sampleRates = {44100, 22050, 11025, 16000};

    public static ExtAudioRecorder getInstanse(Boolean recordingCompressed) {
        ExtAudioRecorder result = null;
        if(recordingCompressed) {
            result = new ExtAudioRecorder(false, AudioSource.MIC, sampleRates[3],
                                          AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                                          AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        } 
        else {
            int i=0;
            do {
                result = new ExtAudioRecorder(true, AudioSource.MIC, sampleRates[i],
                                              AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                                              AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
            } while((++i<sampleRates.length) & 
                   !(result.getState() == ExtAudioRecorder.State.INITIALIZING));
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
    * INITIALIZING : recorder is initializing;
    * READY : recorder has been initialized, recorder not yet started
    * RECORDING : recording
    * ERROR : reconstruction needed
    * STOPPED: reset needed
    */
    public enum State {INITIALIZING, READY, RECORDING, ERROR, STOPPED};
    public static final boolean RECORDING_UNCOMPRESSED = true;
    public static final boolean RECORDING_COMPRESSED = false;

    // The interval in which the recorded samples are output to the file
    // Used only in uncompressed mode
    private static final int TIMER_INTERVAL = 120;

    // Toggles uncompressed recording on/off; 
    // RECORDING_UNCOMPRESSED / RECORDING_COMPRESSED
    private boolean rUncompressed;

    // Recorder used for uncompressed recording
    private AudioRecord audioRecorder = null;

    // Recorder used for compressed recording
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = null;

    // Stores current amplitude (only in uncompressed mode)
    private int cAmplitude = 0;

    // Output file path
    private String filePath = null;

    // Recorder state; see State
    private State state;

    // File writer (only in uncompressed mode)
    private RandomAccessFile randomAccessWriter;

    // Number of channels, sample rate, sample size(size in bits), buffer size, audio source, sample size(see AudioFormat)
    private short nChannels;
    private int sRate;
    private short bSamples;
    private int bufferSize;
    private int aSource;
    private int aFormat;

    // Number of frames written to file on each output(only in uncompressed mode)
    private int framePeriod;

    // Buffer for output(only in uncompressed mode)
    private byte[] buffer;

    // Number of bytes written to file after header(only in uncompressed mode)
    // after stop() is called, this size is written to the header/data chunk in the wave file
    private int payloadSize;

    /**
    * Returns the state of the recorder in a RehearsalAudioRecord.State typed object.
    * Useful, as no exceptions are thrown.
    * @return recorder state
    */
    public State getState() { return state; }

    /**
    * Method used for recording.
    */
    private AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener updateListener = new AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener() {
        public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioRecord recorder) {
            audioRecorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length); // Fill buffer
                try { 
                    randomAccessWriter.write(buffer); // Write buffer to file
                    payloadSize += buffer.length;
                    if (bSamples == 16) {
                        for (int i=0; i<buffer.length/2; i++) { // 16bit sample size
                            short curSample = getShort(buffer[i*2], buffer[i*2+1]);
                            if (curSample > cAmplitude) { // Check amplitude
                                cAmplitude = curSample;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else { // 8bit sample size
                        for (int i=0; i<buffer.length; i++) {
                            if (buffer[i] > cAmplitude) { // Check amplitude
                                cAmplitude = buffer[i];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), 
                          "Error occured in updateListener, recording is aborted");
                    //stop();
                }
            }

            public void onMarkerReached(AudioRecord recorder) {
                // NOT USED
            }
        };

    /** 
    * Default constructor
    * Instantiates a new recorder, in case of compressed recording the parameters can be left as 0.
    * In case of errors, no exception is thrown, but the state is set to ERROR
    */ 
    public ExtAudioRecorder(boolean uncompressed, int audioSource, int sampleRate, 
                            int channelConfig, int audioFormat) {
        try {
            rUncompressed = uncompressed;
            if (rUncompressed) { // RECORDING_UNCOMPRESSED
                if (audioFormat == AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT) {
                    bSamples = 16;
                }
                else { bSamples = 8; }

                if (channelConfig == AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO) {
                    nChannels = 1;
                }
                else { nChannels = 2; }

                aSource = audioSource;
                sRate   = sampleRate;
                aFormat = audioFormat;

                framePeriod = sampleRate * TIMER_INTERVAL / 1000;
                bufferSize = framePeriod * 2 * bSamples * nChannels / 8;
                    if (bufferSize < AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat))
                    { // Check to make sure buffer size is not smaller than the smallest allowed one 
                        bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
                        // Set frame period and timer interval accordingly
                        framePeriod = bufferSize / ( 2 * bSamples * nChannels / 8 );
                        Log.w(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "Increasing buffer size to " + Integer.toString(bufferSize));
                    }

                    audioRecorder = new AudioRecord(audioSource, sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);

                    if (audioRecorder.getState() != AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                        throw new Exception("AudioRecord initialization failed");
                    audioRecorder.setRecordPositionUpdateListener(updateListener);
                    audioRecorder.setPositionNotificationPeriod(framePeriod);
                } else
                { // RECORDING_COMPRESSED
                    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);               
                }
                cAmplitude = 0;
                filePath = null;
                state = State.INITIALIZING;
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (e.getMessage() != null)
                {
                    Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), e.getMessage());
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "Unknown error occured while initializing recording");
                }
                state = State.ERROR;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Sets output file path, call directly after construction/reset.
         *  
         * @param output file path
         * 
         */
        public void setOutputFile(String argPath)
        {
            try
            {
                if (state == State.INITIALIZING)
                {
                    filePath = argPath;
                    if (!rUncompressed)
                    {
                        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(filePath);                  
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (e.getMessage() != null)
                {
                    Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), e.getMessage());
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "Unknown error occured while setting output path");
                }
                state = State.ERROR;
            }
        }

        /**
         * 
         * Returns the largest amplitude sampled since the last call to this method.
         * 
         * @return returns the largest amplitude since the last call, or 0 when not in recording state. 
         * 
         */
        public int getMaxAmplitude()
        {
            if (state == State.RECORDING)
            {
                if (rUncompressed)
                {
                    int result = cAmplitude;
                    cAmplitude = 0;
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return mediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
                    }
                    catch (IllegalStateException e)
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }


        /**
         * 
        * Prepares the recorder for recording, in case the recorder is not in the INITIALIZING state and the file path was not set
        * the recorder is set to the ERROR state, which makes a reconstruction necessary.
        * In case uncompressed recording is toggled, the header of the wave file is written.
        * In case of an exception, the state is changed to ERROR
        *    
        */
        public void prepare()
        {
            try
            {
                if (state == State.INITIALIZING)
                {
                    if (rUncompressed)
                    {
                        if ((audioRecorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) & (filePath != null))
                        {
                            // write file header

                            randomAccessWriter = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "rw");

                            randomAccessWriter.setLength(0); // Set file length to 0, to prevent unexpected behavior in case the file already existed
                            randomAccessWriter.writeBytes("RIFF");
                            randomAccessWriter.writeInt(0); // Final file size not known yet, write 0 
                            randomAccessWriter.writeBytes("WAVE");
                            randomAccessWriter.writeBytes("fmt ");
                            randomAccessWriter.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(16)); // Sub-chunk size, 16 for PCM
                            randomAccessWriter.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes((short) 1)); // AudioFormat, 1 for PCM
                            randomAccessWriter.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes(nChannels));// Number of channels, 1 for mono, 2 for stereo
                            randomAccessWriter.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(sRate)); // Sample rate
                            randomAccessWriter.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(sRate*bSamples*nChannels/8)); // Byte rate, SampleRate*NumberOfChannels*BitsPerSample/8
                            randomAccessWriter.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes((short)(nChannels*bSamples/8))); // Block align, NumberOfChannels*BitsPerSample/8
                            randomAccessWriter.writeShort(Short.reverseBytes(bSamples)); // Bits per sample
                            randomAccessWriter.writeBytes("data");
                            randomAccessWriter.writeInt(0); // Data chunk size not known yet, write 0

                            buffer = new byte[framePeriod*bSamples/8*nChannels];
                            state = State.READY;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "prepare() method called on uninitialized recorder");
                            state = State.ERROR;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mediaRecorder.prepare();
                        state = State.READY;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "prepare() method called on illegal state");
                    release();
                    state = State.ERROR;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                if (e.getMessage() != null)
                {
                    Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), e.getMessage());
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "Unknown error occured in prepare()");
                }
                state = State.ERROR;
            }
        }

        /**
         * 
         * 
         *  Releases the resources associated with this class, and removes the unnecessary files, when necessary
         *  
         */
        public void release()
        {
            if (state == State.RECORDING)
            {
                stop();
            }
            else
            {
                if ((state == State.READY) & (rUncompressed))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        randomAccessWriter.close(); // Remove prepared file
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "I/O exception occured while closing output file");
                    }
                    (new File(filePath)).delete();
                }
            }

            if (rUncompressed)
            {
                if (audioRecorder != null)
                {
                    audioRecorder.release();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (mediaRecorder != null)
                {
                    mediaRecorder.release();
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * 
         * 
         * Resets the recorder to the INITIALIZING state, as if it was just created.
         * In case the class was in RECORDING state, the recording is stopped.
         * In case of exceptions the class is set to the ERROR state.
         * 
         */
        public void reset()
        {
            try
            {
                if (state != State.ERROR)
                {
                    release();
                    filePath = null; // Reset file path
                    cAmplitude = 0; // Reset amplitude
                    if (rUncompressed)
                    {
                        audioRecorder = new AudioRecord(aSource, sRate, nChannels+1, aFormat, bufferSize);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                    }
                    state = State.INITIALIZING;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), e.getMessage());
                state = State.ERROR;
            }
        }

        /**
         * 
         * 
         * Starts the recording, and sets the state to RECORDING.
         * Call after prepare().
         * 
         */
        public void start()
        {
            if (state == State.READY)
            {
                if (rUncompressed)
                {
                    payloadSize = 0;
                    audioRecorder.startRecording();
                    audioRecorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                }
                else
                {
                    mediaRecorder.start();
                }
                state = State.RECORDING;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "start() called on illegal state");
                state = State.ERROR;
            }
        }

        /**
         * 
         * 
         *  Stops the recording, and sets the state to STOPPED.
         * In case of further usage, a reset is needed.
         * Also finalizes the wave file in case of uncompressed recording.
         * 
         */
        public void stop()
        {
            if (state == State.RECORDING)
            {
                if (rUncompressed)
                {
                    audioRecorder.stop();

                    try
                    {
                        randomAccessWriter.seek(4); // Write size to RIFF header
                        randomAccessWriter.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(36+payloadSize));

                        randomAccessWriter.seek(40); // Write size to Subchunk2Size field
                        randomAccessWriter.writeInt(Integer.reverseBytes(payloadSize));

                        randomAccessWriter.close();
                    }
                    catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "I/O exception occured while closing output file");
                        state = State.ERROR;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    mediaRecorder.stop();
                }
                state = State.STOPPED;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e(ExtAudioRecorder.class.getName(), "stop() called on illegal state");
                state = State.ERROR;
            }
        }

        /* 
         * 
         * Converts a byte[2] to a short, in LITTLE_ENDIAN format
         * 
         */
        private short getShort(byte argB1, byte argB2)
        {
            return (short)(argB1 | (argB2 << 8));
        }

    }
```

And i m using that class in my main activity as here ..i m recording sound on button click and stop it on another button click

package com.test.android_recorder;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class AndroidRecorder extends Activity {
     ExtAudioRecorder extAudioRecorder;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.test.android_recorder.R.layout.activity_android_recorder);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        Button buttonstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonstop);

        // Start recording
           extAudioRecorder = ExtAudioRecorder.getInstanse(true);   


        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View v)
          {

TextView txt1=(TextView)findViewById(com.test.android_recorder.R.id.textView1);
              txt1.setText("Button clciked");

                 // Compressed recording (AMR)
                    //extAudioRecorder = ExtAudioRecorder.getInstanse(false); // Uncompressed recording (WAV)

                    extAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/javarecorder");
                    extAudioRecorder.prepare();
                    extAudioRecorder.start();


              // ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
             //iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
        });



        buttonstop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
          public void onClick(View v)
          {

//TextView txt1=(TextView)findViewById(com.test.android_recorder.R.id.textView1);
             // txt1.setText("Button clciked");
              // ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
             //iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

              // Stop recording
              extAudioRecorder.stop();
              extAudioRecorder.release();
          }
        });




        /*


*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(com.test.android_recorder.R.menu.activity_android_recorder, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

My Problem is that now file is recording but the recorded file is too noisy and unclear.i want to use this recorded file in sphinx 4 speech recgnition.and its require 16000KHZ 16 bit mono big endian..but when i use the recorded file in my sphhinx4 speech recognition then it give me unsupported source error...i want to make my wav file quality good...how can i?
Please Help me Out

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Sorry For mistake..i have edited my question...please guide me..thanx in advance

Comment: So what rate and precision is the file being recorded at?  (Examine the file with Audacity or some such on your Mac.)  And "noisy" does not equate with poor bit rate -- "muddy", perhaps, if the bit rate is really low, and just not "bright" sounding if the bit rate is mediocre.

Answer (score 0):

```
private final static int[] sampleRates = {44100, 22050, 11025, 8000};
```

none of these sampleRates are 16khz.

**Edit:**
`illegal state` often times indicates that you don't have the permission added in your `manifest.xml`.

Comment: ya but atleast first i can record with any of these khz///but that evn nt happening..and that recordedn format can not be played in any media player..whys this things happening?

Comment: @BhavikKama -- Have you tried actually *setting* 16000KHz & 16 bit?

Comment: and maybe try one step at a time. I would try to first record at 16Khz (16000Khz seems to be too fricking much) and then try 16bit and in a last step the Endianess.

Comment: sorry For Typing mistake .it means 16Khz or 16000Hz